# Perl module function call runs in spite of missing use statement

Tags: perl

I'm developing in a library consisting of multiple Perl modules.

The following statement compiles and runs perfectly:

```
my $x = Foo::Bar::new();
```

But the necessary `use` statement is missing from the beginning of the module:

```
use Foo::Bar;
```

How is this possible? Is `use` propagating from used or using modules?

Comment: I'm not trying to solve a problem. I'm wondering why I don't have a problem. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some background first.

```
use Foo::Bar;
```

is short for

```
BEGIN {
    require Foo::Bar;
    import Foo::Bar;
}
```

`import Foo::Bar;` calls the `import` method of the module if one exists. This happens every time `use` is used. With no arguments, most modules' `import` export a default list of symbols or none at all.

If you don't need to import anything (as is the case in your program), you can forgo the import by using

```
use Foo::Bar ();
```

It's a special case equivalent to

```
BEGIN {
    require Foo::Bar;
}
```

`require Foo::Bar;` is what loads the module. The modules is only loaded (executed) once per interpreter no matter how many times you do `require Foo::Bar;` (or `use Foo::Bar;`).

In your case, you probably loaded a module that loaded Foo::Bar. That allows you to omit `use Foo::Bar ();` since it wouldn't have done anything anyway.

Comment: So the key is: modules are loaded once per interpreter. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't show any significant code, but one of the modules that you *do* use probably loads `Foo::Bar`, making it available to code in every package.

It doesn't matter where the `use` (or `require`) appears, as long as it is done before the code that depends on it is executed

Comment: Re "It doesn't matter where the `use` (or `require`) appears, as long as it is done before the code that depends on it is executed", That's not true. `perl -E'package XXX; use MIME::Base64; encode_base64("abc"); package YYY; encode_base64("def")'`

Comment: @ikegami: *"could be populated by a different module"* is the scenario I described. You say yourself, *"you probably loaded a module that loaded Foo::Bar"*. We agree that it is highly unlikely that the core modules are involved. Your second comment involves a missing *import*, which is irrelevant because the call `Foo::Bar::new` is fully-qualified